# wpf calendar appears empty when displaymode is year or decade

Tags: wpf, calendar

i have a standard calendar control defined in my xaml file:

```
<Calendar Height="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,0,0,0"
Name="NewCalendarYear" Width="200" SelectedDatesChanged="NewCalendarYear_SelectedDatesChanged" DisplayMode="Decade" />
```

the problem I am having is that it works properly when DisplayMode="Month", but when changing it to "Year" or "Decade" the Calendar appears empty... with one arrow pointing to the left (i am not allowed to upload images). I have been searching but I have not found a sample of any xaml calendar code that works properly in these displaymodes.

Thanks¡¡

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was having the same issue.

There's some kind of bug with setting the DisplayMode in XAML.  If you set it in the codebehind, on the _Load event, it will work!

Comment: Thank you for sharing this!  I've struggled for several hours trying to figure this out.  I thought I had tried everything.  This did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

##### It´s the Year 2022 and within Net 6.0 this issue still exists...

With the previous answer and some research i have found a solution for me that works.

Unfortunately the **Loaded- Event** is not enough, if you like to keep the display Mode as it is set... (as microsoft tells [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.calendar.displaymode?view=windowsdesktop-6.0#examples) ... YAY!^^)

Here is my Example Workaround in Codebehind.
I have used DisplayMode **"Year"**.

*First i have assigned the **Loaded- Event** of the calendar control within XAML*

**View.xaml:**

```xml
    <Calendar
       Loaded="Calendar_OnLoaded"
       Width="auto"
       DisplayDate="{x:Static sys:DateTime.Now}"
       />
```

*Second the Codebehind Workaround*

**View.xaml.cs**

```cs
// set Display Mode after calender is loaded for the first time and subscribe "DisplayModeChanged" Event
private void Calendar_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Calendar calObj = sender as Calendar;
        calObj.DisplayMode = CalendarMode.Year;
        calObj.DisplayModeChanged += new EventHandler<CalendarModeChangedEventArgs> (Calendar_DisplayModeChanged);
    }
// set Display Mode each time user has made a selection within calender
private void Calendar_DisplayModeChanged(object sender,
                                         CalendarModeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Calendar calObj = sender as Calendar;

        calObj.DisplayMode = CalendarMode.Year;
    }
```